# Pivot/Unstack Pandas Dataframe Data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Grateful for your help.  Sorry, could not figure this out as I wasn't sure if I'm pivoting or unstacking.

My data looks like this:

| Email | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| si@si | A | 2 | D |
| ad@ad | A | 5 | C |

I'm looking to pivot this to:

|  | si@si | ad@ad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Col1 | A | A |
| Col2 | 2 | 5 |
| Col3 | D | C |

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transpose the dataFrame.

```
df.set_index('Email').rename_axis(None).T
```